# service procedure in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86-16

The service procedure for case number 90H is given in the com.x file:

```
 jmp initialize
    msg db "this is isr90$"
    isr90 proc
    push ax
    push dx
    push ds
    lea dx, cs:msg
    mov ah, 9
    int 21H
    pop ds
    pop dx
    pop ax
    iret
    endp
    initialize:
```

a.exe

```
data
 msg db "this is easy", 0ah, 0dh
 x db 300 dup("$")
.CODE
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
lea dx, msg
mov ah, 9
int 21H
int 90H
mov ah, 4ch
 int 21H
endp
```

First run the com.x file and then the exe.a file. What will be printed on the screen?

1. this is easy
2. this is easy  this is isr90
3. easy is this and then gibberish
4. this is easy  this is easy

Comment: Do not expect others to do homework for you.

Comment: @fuz: I answered because the homework question is bad.

Comment: The part after the label `initialize` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know.

The service routine is buggy It uses `ds` without initializing it. The problem is solvable given whole programs, but we don't have whole programs. With some reasonable assumptions, we can come to an answer, but these may be wrong.

Assumptions:

- We have a three pass assembler that automatically uses the shortest possible jmp.
- The a.exe is compiled as an MZ executable that puts the data segment before the code segment (abnormal for higher-level languages, but with this layout in the `.asm` file it may well do this), and loaded at the lowest possible address (reasonable).
- Everything is built using the tiny memory model.

The output would be:

```
this is easy
is is easy
```

Because under these assumptions, `ds:0100` points to the message this is easy, but `dx` is 0102 in the ISR so it points two bytes into the message.

Comment: Interrupt flag off on DOS entry is no problem. (DOS may internally enable interrupts though.) However, DOS is not reentrant and thus should not be called while another DOS call is in progress. That is only relevant for hardware IRQs though. As their int 90h is only called from the "foreground" execution, and it is valid at that point to make a DOS call, it is not in error.